# python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully , installing the psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

I just want to install psycopg2 and I get the following error message:

```
PS D:\Visualalize_data> pip3 install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.9.5.tar.gz (384 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      D:\Python\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      g2._psycopg' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
Failed to build psycopg2
Installin
      running build
      legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> psycopg2

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

What I have already tried:

pip install nes-py --no-cache-dir
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
My system:

Windows 10
Python 3.10.2 64 Bit
Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing what the messege tells you to and downloaded
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater?
You can install it at "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/